# Adding Strings through input to .txt file in Python

Tags: python, file, append

The output i receive is "none" while in the .txt file is already 3 given names and i suppose to add one more through input.

```
Add a new member: Solomon Right
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

That is my code:

```
newUserMember = input("Add a new member: ")

file = open("/Users/nikitalutsai/Downloads/members.txt", 'r')
content = file.readlines()
file.close()

content.append(newUserMember + "\n")

file = open("/Users/nikitalutsai/Downloads/members.txt", 'w')
content = file.writelines(content)
print(content)
```

Comment: `writelines` returns `None`. What are you trying to do? The file should contain the expected names.

Answer (score 0):

`writelines` is returning `None` as mentioned in the comment [(see here)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_writelines.htm). If you want to append to a file you should have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-i-append-to-a-file).

Do something like:

```
with open("/Users/nikitalutsai/Downloads/members.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(input("Add a new member: "))
```